# nativescript firebase plugin, query by field

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular2-nativescript

I am using [nativescript-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase) to query firebase database in my angular2-nativescript application. I went through the [documentation](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/DATABASE.md) on how to query the database by field. For example I would like to fetch address of a user, based on uid for the below example database. But I could not find a way. Any help will be appreciated.

```
{
  "address" : {
    "-KfBtEuTA43UzSFfK7kU" : {
      "house_number" : "hno1",
      "street" : "street1",
      "city" : "city1",
      "uid" : "0P3Km5i9cEd1Akg7gJfJnALUSZw2"
    },
    "-KfC4Myo69bTZQCzw1yz" : {
      "house_number" : "hno2",
      "street" : "street2",
      "city" : "city2",
      "uid" : "4sj3ADekxsVNf5RaAFjbLbF6x0K2"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The documentation for the native script plugin has an example of how to query: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/DATABASE.md#query. Unless you show what you've tried already, I doubt any of us will be able to explain better than Eddy did there.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen My bad. I was thinking that the interface will be similar to AngularFire list query: 'angularFire.database.list("/address/", {
            query: {
              orderByChild: 'uid',
              equalTo: userData.uid
            }
          });'
Now, I got the solution. I will answer my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code gave me the query result by uid.

```
  firebase.query(result => {
    console.log("query result:", JSON.stringify(result));
  }, "/address", {
    orderBy: {
      type: firebase.QueryOrderByType.CHILD,
      value: 'uid'
    },
    ranges: [
      {
        type: firebase.QueryRangeType.START_AT,
        value: uidValue
      },
      {
        type: firebase.QueryRangeType.END_AT,
        value: uidValue
      }
    ]
  })
```

Comment: in OrderBy I give value is 'Status'. In ranges, I give value : 'New' for both START_AT and END_AT. I coulnt get the result. Can you help me?